# Who is the Gift of God?

Tags: riddle

> They say he is more than a hero!
>   Don't believe? He can divide by zero!
>   He lives in the land of Big Ben
>   If you are reading this, then you are near his den!
>
> Most reputed among us all,
>   Yet, as it is, his name is small!
>   Now, it's a verb, something only he can do,
>   Tell me his name. Can you?

Comment: zero! = 0! = 1. Anyone can do it. :p

Comment: @manshu 0! =1. Good point. But `zero!` != `0!` :)

Comment: "its a verb"... "it's a verb" ftfy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My Guess:

> [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)

They say he is more than a hero! (preamble only)

Don't believe, he can divide by zero!

> See [Jon Skeet Facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/9138/revisions)

He lives in the land of Big Ben

> He lives in the UK.

If you are reading this, then you are near his den!

> https://stackoverflow.com/

Most reputed among us all,

> 863k Rep on SO.

Yet, as it is, his name is small!

> Jon is pretty short, as is Skeet

Now it's a verb, something only he can do

> With help from OP:  [To be skeeted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts/9218#9218) 
>  
>  Original Answer: [See Definition 3](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/skeet) -- But there might be "Jon Skeet-ing" in use on S.O. I can't find a reference though.

Tell me his name. Can you?

> Yes, I can.

Comment: I'd like some help on the Verb line.  I'm positive about the rest.

Comment: You are right! Now, for the verb thing, see this : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9218/315859

Comment: Hey, but you never said what the title meant!

Comment: "Skeet" as a verb also has a less-savory meaning (check Urban Dictionary (while not at work)).